# Azure static webapp?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I have a static web app there I can able to add only 5 domains (URL) but I want to map more than 15 URLs.

instead of creating new static web app, any other alternate way.

FYI - I am using azure devops and its pipeline to do the deployment from the master branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, According to this [***MS Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/quotas)

> The default limit of custom domain for Azure Static Web app is 5 given your static web app is created under a Standard Plan.

This limitation seems to be by Product design thus, Its not possible to increase it.

*You can increase the quota by raising a support request for the services below:-*

[image]

Comment: after increasing, do we get new limit?

Comment: Unfortunately, For static web app custom domain the limit of 5 is by design. Thus it cannot be increased. Only the services included in the screenshot above are eligible for quota increase.